# redirecting back to index page after posting in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, alert

I am trying to insert transactions to mysql database by using a php/html page. I am able to insert data to mysql DB successfully. After successful inserting, i require an alert "record added successfully" and redirect the page back to index page with a refresh.
here is my index page and action page. please help.

Php code (Action)

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pra@181178","ayrilmana");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

  $sql = "INSERT INTO dlbcc_purchase (txn_type,purch_date, purch_amt, purch_dtls, due_date) VALUES ('"  . $_POST['txn_type'] . "','"  . $_POST['purch_date'] . "', '" .$_POST['purch_amt'] . "','" . $_POST['purch_dtls'] . "','" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['due_date'])) . "')";

  print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert ('Record Added Successfully.');
        window.location.hrf = addtxnindex.php;
        </script>";

  }
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//echo "1 record added";
//Header( "Location: addtxnindex.php" );

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Tell us, why the contents of the index-page is relevant here. If you can't do this, just delete the bunch of tags. No one wants to read useless tags...

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace **print** with

```
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function redir()
{
alert('record added..');
window.location.assign('index.php');
}
</script>
<body onload='redir();'></body>";
```

Comment: Thats okey bro.. but your code have lots of faults so please use these codes for learning purpose only..

Comment: I understand that... i have just started learning php. Thanks for the support.

Comment: one more doubt. is it possible to alert the message on the same page? now it is going to the action page and alerting the moving back to index page automatically. is it possible to alert the message on the same page?